# Установка и настройка Gulp

Tags: gulp

Прохожу обучение установки Gulp (пишу, чтобы показать, что я не умею работать с ним и не могу исправить ошибку), после команды

```
npm install gulp --save-dev
```

создает папку `node_modules`, в которой куча папок и весит 4мб. Как это исправить (чтобы была стандартная папка с вложенностью `bin` и `gulp`) и почему возникает такая проблема ?

Comment: Это не баг, это фича. https://docs.npmjs.com/files/folders#node-modules

Comment: могли бы вы подсказать, как это исправить, потому как я не силен в Gulp'е и это сбивает с толку ?

Comment: тот факт, что создается папка `node_modules` исправлять не надо. так работает npm

Comment: Я понимаю, но как сделать так, чтобы в ней были всего две папки, как в обучении (gulp и bin) ? Ведь при туториале у них именно так устанавливается .

Comment: Понятия не имею, как в вашем туториале это делается. Ни npm ни gulp **не создают** папки `gulp` и `bin`. Скорее всего, либо туториал кривой, либо вы его не так читаете.

Comment: Вы можете ознакомиться: 
https://css-tricks.com/gulp-for-beginners/

Comment: Да, вы не умеете читать. В руководстве четко сказано, что папки `gulp` и `.bin` должны появится внутри `node_modules`.

Comment: "_You should also see a `gulp` folder within `node_modules`._"

Comment: Да, они есть, но также там есть куча других папки, о которых совершенно ничего не упоминается. Извините, что возможно Вас раздражаю, но меня действительно волнует данный вопрос. Значит эти папки всегда присутствуют, их нельзя никак удалить и о них просто не пишут рассказчики ?

Comment: Наличие других папок вызвано разными версиями npm у вас и у авторов руководства. Рискну предложить, что у них `npm@2.x.x` а у вас `npm@3.x.x` (можете вызвать `npm -v`). Как бы то ни было **никаких проблем** у вас с установкой gulp нет.

Comment: )) Вот, теперь мне стало ясно, спасибо за ответ! Еще раз извините, если утомил Вас своими вопросами, это вызвано недопониманием. 
Не буду удалять пока вопрос, возможно кто-то знает, как сделать чистую папку, интересно посмотреть решение. Спасибо за Ваше разъяснение. .

Comment: Еще раз. Вам не нужна "чистая папка". Содержимое `node_modules` вообще должно вас волновать в последнюю очередь. Все что там есть попадает туда исключительно посредством `npm`.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для новичков: 
1) Возможно ваша версия npm и версия в различных tutorial'ах отличается, из-за этого возникает подобная ситуация, переживать по этому поводу не стоит. 
2) Папка node_modules вообще не должна вызывать у вас какие-то эмоции, все, что там есть и попадает туда исключительно с помощью npm.